# Reading values from a file, updating values, and writing back to file - Python

Tags: python

I have a CSV file containing different parameters and results for a test, that looks like the following:

```
Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4  Pass  Fail  Result
   1     1     1     1     0     0       0
   3     5     6    14     0     0       0
```

What I would like to do is read the line from the file (neglecting the first line, of course), run the test, then repeatedly update the 'Pass', 'Fail', and 'Result' part of the line. Some pseudocode/real code to help explain some more:

```
def readfile():
  fp = open('foo.csv', 'r+')
  lines = fp.readlines()[1:]
  for i in range(0, len(lines)):
      line = lines[i]
      # depending on test result, Pass or Fail will be updated, here Pass will be updated
      line[4] += 1
      # write line[4] back to file
      # keep updating the Pass or Fail until a condition is met then go to next line
```

Is there a way to do this, and would it also be possible that the file mode I'm using wouldn't allow this?

Comment: You shouldn't write back to the same file you are reading from. You should make a new file with the new lines.

Comment: That was plan B, I was just wondering whether there was any way to do this or not.

Comment: You could wait until the condition is met to write to the file. If you need to see realtime results, read, write, and close to it each time you need to change it. Then view it on another program.

Answer (score 0):

I have too low a rep to comment so here is my comment as an answer.
What if you used two files. One for your input values and one for your output results for your test.
Then in your loop you could locally hold the values of pass, fail and result incrementing them until your condition is met and at that time write the result line to the output file.
An index or just row number could be used to keep the results and the input in files correlated.